# How to fix a C # wrapper for C ++?

Tags: c#, c++, c, visual-c++, wincc

I am trying to call a function from a dll. Description of the function in C ++:

```
BOOL WINAPI PDLCSGetPropertyEx(LPCTSTR lpszProjectName, LPCTSTR lpszPictureName, LPCTSTR lpszObjectName, LPCTSTR lpszPropName, VARTYPE vt, LPVOID pvProp, DWORD dwFlags, LPVOID pData, PCMN_ERROR pError);
```

In C # I have written:

```
[DllImport("pdlcsapi.dll", EntryPoint = "PDLCSGetPropertyEx", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    public static extern bool PDLCSGetPropertyEx(
        [In] String lpszProjectName,
        [In] String lpszPictureName,
        [In] String lpszObjectName,
        [In] String lpszPropName,
        VarEnum vt,
         IntPtr pvProp,
        [In] UInt32 dwFlags,
        [In] IntPtr pData,
        [In,Out] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] CMN_ERROR_MANCLASS pError
        );
```

and the call in the application:

```
WinCCODK_PDLCS.CMN_ERROR_MANCLASS errPdl;
        errPdl = new WinCCODK_PDLCS.CMN_ERROR_MANCLASS();
        IntPtr p = new IntPtr();
        String propName = listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
        String objName = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        bool ret = WinCCODK_PDLCS.CPDLCSWrapper.PDLCSGetPropertyEx(
            "C:\\DemoProjectV72_Light\\DemoProjectV72_Light.mcp"
            , "io.pdl"
            , objName
            , propName
            , VarEnum.VT_I4
            , p
            , 0
            , IntPtr.Zero
            , errPdl ); 
        if (ret){
            listBox2.Items[listBox2.SelectedIndex] = listBox2.Items[listBox2.SelectedIndex] + val.ToString();
        }else{
            MessageBox.Show(errPdl.szErrorText);
        }
```

After calling this function, the application falls (there is a standard Windows window stopped working program)

**How to pass parameters to a function?**

Other features of this library are working fine. .

I think that does not work correctly with the parameters **vt** and **PvProp**. These are described in the documentation:

> vt 
>   Data type of the value passed with pvProp. Valid types are defined
>   in the "VARENUM" enumeration within the "wtypes.h" Include file
>   belonging to the compiler. No VT_VARIANT, VT_DISPATCH or other
>   references should be used.
>
> PvProp 
>   Pointer to a tag to which the property value is saved. The data
>   type of the value is determined by vt. For pvProp you can specify any
>   value defined for the Variant data type; refer to the values contained
>   in the "wtypes.h" Include file belonging to your compiler. For types
>   which have a buffer (e.g. BSTR), the buffer is allocated by the
>   function and must be cleared afterwards by the calling application.

Comment: What does your debugger tell you about the crash?

Comment: I only see this window: http://prntscr.com/e9j6dz

Comment: I'm sure, one of the options is to attach a debugger. You should.

Comment: here's a short video: http://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cbnDDn6lQR

Comment: Your debugger should have the capability to attach. Make sure your compiler and IDE is up-to-date. For Windows you probably want the latest Visual Studio 2017 RC.

Comment: An unhandled exception at 0x10009D97 (PDLCSAPI.dll) in CCDotNet_CSharp_WindowsApplication_DMClient.exe: 0xC0000005: Access Violation when writing to the address 0x00000000.